# Overlapping graphs using R or Excel

Tags: excel, r, graph, overlap

I have following matrix and I want to draw overlapping graph using R (preferable) or Excel.

```
    a       b       c
a   1       0.5     0.7
b   0.5     1       0.4
c   0.7     0.4     1
```

For example, the above table shows that `a` and `b` have 50% overlapping, whereas `a` and `c` have 70%.

Comment: Are you lloking for something like a Venn diagram?

Comment: @Aniko, yes Venn diagram using above data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428946/venn-diagrams-with-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want overlapping then you missed one number - overlapping all three: `a`, `b`, `c`.

As Aniko write in comment you could use Venn diagrams, e.g. [Vennerable from R-forge](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/vennerable/).

Installation need some packages from BioConductor:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite(c("graph", "RBGL", "gtools", "xtable"))
install.packages("Vennerable", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

You mast prepare your data properly:

```
require(Vennerable)
x <- Venn(
    SetNames = c("a", "b", "c"),
    Weight = c(`100`=1,   `010`=1,   `001`=1,
               `110`=0.5, `101`=0.7, `011`=0.4,
               `111`=.5) # I made this up cause your question miss it
)
```

And voilà:

```
plot(x, doWeights=TRUE)
```

[image: Venn diagram]

---

Some additional explanations.

Data structures for Vennerable package need to provide set names (`"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"` in your case) and frequencies/proportions of each intersects. This 0/1 names identify subsets: `1` means "in set", `0` means "not in set". So e.g.:

- `100` means in `a`, not in `b`, not in `c`,
- `011` means not in `a`, in `b`, in `c`

So `111` means in all three sets, which is missing in your matrix and it can't be added there. For your sample data when a&b has 0.7 overlapping and b&c has 0.4 means that at least 0.1 is in three set at the same time (or I missed interpretation of this numbers). (note: I think I overestimated this 0.5, cause it should be lower than 0.4)

You could prepare your data to Venn plot before creating matrix, e.g:

```
X <- list(
    a = c("One", "Two", "Three"),
    b = c("One", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Seven"),
    c = c("Three", "Five", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten")
)

x <- Venn(X)
x
# A Venn object on 3 sets named
# a,b,c 
# 000 100 010 110 001 101 011 111 
#   0   1   2   1   3   0   1   1 
plot(x, doWeights=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain little bit more that how did you mapped my matrix in your function? and why did you add another 0.5? Where can I put this number in my matrix? What are 101, 110, or 100 values? In addition, my values are 0.003,0.0047 etc. Will it create problems?

Comment: @user751637 I add some explanations. Check it is answer your doubts.