# Identifying elements of a vector which is not found in another comparable vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I want to know the exact elements of a vector not found in the vector. For instance, consider the following vectors:

```
veca <- c("ab", "cd", "ef", "gh", "ij", "kl")
vecb <- c("ab", "ef", "ij", "kl")
```

From this, `cd` and `gh` are in `veca` but not in `vecb`. How can one identify these elements in R? Thanks!

Comment: `not_in_vecb <- veca[!veca %in% vecb]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two character vectors in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598134/compare-two-character-vectors-in-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could define a custom function like an opposite intersect function using `setdiff`:

learned [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2011/11/outersect-the-opposite-of-rs-intersect-function/):

```
outersect <- function(x, y) {
  sort(c(setdiff(x, y),
         setdiff(y, x)))
}

outersect(veca, vecb)
```

output:

```
[1] "cd" "gh"
```

Another possible solution is:

```
not_in_vecb <- veca[!veca %in% vecb]

[1] "cd" "gh"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `%in%` operator

Identifying elements in `veca` that are not in `vecb`

```
> veca[!(veca %in% vecb)]
[1] "cd" "gh"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here we consider a bit more general case

```
veca <- c("ab", "cd", "ef", "gh", "ij", "kl") # "cd" and "gh" are not in `vecb`
vecb <- c("ab", "ef", "ij", "kl", "xy") # "xy" is not in `veca`
```

---

Below are some options we can try

1. `set` operations: `union`, `setdiff`, and `intersect`

```
> setdiff(union(veca, vecb), intersect(veca, vecb))
[1] "cd" "gh" "xy"
```

2. `stack` + `subset` to filter out whose occurrence is just `1`

```
subset(
  aggregate(
    ind ~ .,
    stack(list(a = veca, b = vecb)),
    unique
  ),
  lengths(ind) == 1,
  select = values
)
```

which gives

```
  values
2     cd
4     gh
7     xy
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the builtin function `setdiff()`

Example:

```
veca <- c("ab", "cd", "ef", "gh", "ij", "kl")
vecb <- c("ab", "ef", "ij", "kl")


print(setdiff(veca, vecb))
```

Output:

```
[1] "cd" "gh"
```