# How to draw a venn diagram subset by a main vector in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame such like this:

```
df<-data.frame(
    A=rep(1, 10),
    B=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 1, 0,0),
    C=c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    D=c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)
)
df
   A B C D
1  1 1 0 0
2  1 1 0 1
3  1 1 0 1
4  1 1 1 1
5  1 1 1 1
6  1 1 1 1
7  1 1 1 1
8  1 1 1 1
9  1 0 1 1
10 1 0 1 0
```

My question is how to draw a venn diagram in R such like below where B,C,D are subset to A.
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428946/venn-diagrams-with-r may be relevant

Comment: Thanks. Have tried all these. Seems not very satisfying.

Comment: I currently used venn but seems not what I wanted like this post.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand the question, but it looks like a *non sequitur* with the first part. If you have a data frame with some data, the look of the diagram will depend on those data. If you want that particular diagram, you might consider my `nVennR` package like this:

```
> library(nVennR)
> myV <- createVennObj(nSets = 4, sNames = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))
> myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c('A', 'B'), 1)
> myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c('A', 'C'), 1)
> myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c('A', 'B', 'D'), 2)
> myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c('A', 'C', 'D'), 1)
> myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), 5)
> myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)
> showSVG(myV, opacity = 0.1, borderWidth = 3)
```

And the result:
[image: Euler diagram]

If you are interested, you can see the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nVennR/vignettes/nVennR.html) for more options.