# How to create a Venn Diagram using R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gplots

I created a Venn Diagram using the eulerr package but it doesn't let me customize it and the outlines of the inner circles seem to touch the sample space circle. I looked through the VennDiagram package manual but had no luck. Is there a way to create a Venn Diagram using either ggplot2 or any other R packages.

I am looking to do what this user was trying to do with the data I have. 3 sets that fall into the complete sample space. [How to draw a venn diagram subset by a main vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35873126/how-to-draw-a-venn-diagram-subset-by-a-main-vector-in-r)

This is what was created using the eulerr package:

[image: from https://imgur.com/a/Zh37gaR]

This is the data that I have. Circles B, C, and D should be inside circle A which has a total of 141. The 35 in variable a is the space between the 3 venn diagram and the circle (white space).

```
b = c(50,0,9,2,1,0,0,0)
c = c(50,21,0,2,0,3,0,0)
d = c(50,21,9,2,0,3,20,0)
a = c(50, 21, 9, 2,1,3,20,35)
```

totes = cbind(b, c, d, a)

I don't know how to go about this and make a presentable diagram that I can customize.

When I used the eulerr package, I manually entered the data in the command.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Answer (score 1):

You may consider my `nVennR` package. With your data,

```
>library(nVennR)
> myV <- plotVenn(list(b = c(50,9,2,1),
+                      c = c(50,21,2,3),
+                      d = c(50,21,9,2,3,20),
+                      a = c(50, 21, 9, 2,1,3,20,35)))
> showSVG(myV, opacity = 0.2, borderWidth = 1)
```

And the result:

[image: cont2]

You can also list the elements in each region:

```
> listVennRegions(myV)
$`0, 0, 0, 1 (a)`
[1] 35

$`0, 0, 1, 1 (d, a)`
[1] 20

$`0, 1, 1, 1 (c, d, a)`
[1] 21  3

$`1, 0, 0, 1 (b, a)`
[1] 1

$`1, 0, 1, 1 (b, d, a)`
[1] 9

$`1, 1, 1, 1 (b, c, d, a)`
[1] 50  2
```

Please, notice that I removed the zeroes in your list. The package takes those zeroes as elements, which were not present in list a. If you are interested, you can find a [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nVennR/vignettes/nVennR.html) and a [web interface](http://degradome.uniovi.es/cgi-bin/nVenn/nvenn.cgi) for the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am looking to create a plot similar to what I have posted.