# nVennr. Change standard form figures and remove legend

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I am using nVennr, which has proved to be quite useful, although have been through all of the supporting documentation and still can't find out how to do 2 things that I am imagine are possible. They are how to change the displayed figures to non-standard-form format, and how to remove the legend.

Below is some data that illustrates how nVennr automatically converts figures to standard form.

```
library(nVennr)
library(dplyr)
library(rsvg)
library(grImport2)

SetA = round(runif(10000000),0)
SetB = round(runif(10000000),0)
SetC = round(runif(10000000),0)

allSets = cbind(SetA, SetB, SetC) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column()

SetA = subset(allSets, SetA == 1)$rowname
SetB = subset(allSets, SetB == 1)$rowname
SetC = subset(allSets, SetC == 1)$rowname

myV = plotVenn(list(SetA = SetA,
                SetB = SetB,
                SetC = SetC),
           nCycles = 10000)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, in particular with the standard form issue, and this renders the plots quite ugly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Glad you like the package. I am not sure what you mean by *standard form*. Perhaps you want one of those diagrams with three overlapping circles. In that case, I would recommend using other packages, like those suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428946/venn-diagrams-with-r). You can get a **regular** Venn diagram with `nVennR`, as shown in the vignette, but the default shape is always round in the `region`, not in the `set`:

```
library(nVennR)
myV3 <- createVennObj(nSets = 3, sSizes = c(rep(1, 8)))
myV3 <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV3, labelRegions=F, showNumbers=F, opacity=0.2, borderWidth=4)
```

The result would be:

[image: Regular Venn diagram]

Regarding the legend, I did not think that would be necessary, as it is very easy to remove from the resulting `svg` file. However, since I need to upload a new version, I will add this function shortly.

EDIT:
The new version of `nVennR` (0.2.2) has just been released. Now, `plotVenn` and `showSVG` have the option `showLegend`. If set to `false`, the legend is not shown.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the very late response to this, although what I meant by 'standard form' was the standard index notation on the numerical labels, such as '1.234000E6' etc. For my particular use case I needed numerical labels in non-standard index notation format, and whatever I tried couldn't undo that (eg using scipen etc). Anyway, have yet to look at the new version of nVennR(0.2.2) although will do when I have a chance.