# How to create a venn diagram with unlimited sets?

Tags: python, matplotlib, venn-diagram, matplotlib-venn

I have come across `matplotlib_venn` module which support 2-3 sets and `venn` module that can support up to 6 sets, is there a tool that supports an unlimited amount of sets?
Can you somehow achieve that by using these tools?

EDIT:
Assuming I'm using `UpSetPlot` as suggested in the comments, can I also add some functionality to the bars? like by clicking a specific bar I can open a list that contains the elements inside that intersection?

Comment: I can't help with the venn diagram, but if you're using more than 6 sets I would recommend you look into UpSet plots, which scale better than venn diagrams in terms of comprehensibility when approaching, as it were, unlimited sets.

Comment: There is a comprehensive thread about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428946/venn-diagrams-with-r

Comment: @Plasma I looked into it and you are right - it is absolutely more comprehensible.  Do you know if there is a feature on this module such as I described in the edit?